# Checking if the value for the key is the same as before

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been working on this code and I cannot find a answer.

1. I have 2 lists

   ```
   point_values = [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10]

   letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
   ```
2. I want to set `a:1` and `b:3` and so on...and I want them put in a dictionary called `point_letters`.

This is my starter code.

```
point_letters = {}
point_values = [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10]
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

for x in letters:
    for i in point_values:
        if point_letters[x] != i: # is what I'm trying to do
            point_letters[x] = i
print(point_letters)
```

How should I do this?

Comment: for starters, don't start with a `list` of the same name as your desired output `dict` :) but more importantly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: woops im so tired i typed that wrong

Comment: what's the actual problem you're facing? Assigning the two lists to a dictionary of key=letters:value=point_values?

Comment: Why are you not just creating a dictionary in the first place?

Comment: it is a requierment

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Kinda but its for person reference too.

Comment: So i can look back on this problem if I ever have it again

Comment: I'll repeat myself in case you didn't see it 1 minute ago: what's the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: You appear to be asking how to check the current value a dict is holding for a particular key without getting an error - correct?  If so, add the traceback to your question so we can discuss what went wrong, and why you don't want to do that anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
point_letters = dict(zip(letters, point_values))
```

`zip` makes a list of pairs of corresponding elements; `dict` converts the list of pairs to a dictionary.

EDIT: changed the dict name. Also in response to comments, and the posted code:

> This is great, but I still have not learned this. Is there a way to for loop it?

In general, in the real world, you'd use the above method. `for` is very low-level and you'd want to avoid it when you can. For the class, I won't solve your problem, but give you hints instead (so it's not plagiarism):

- You want to pair up the `letters[i]` and `point_values[i]` for the same `i`
- `i` should be going from `0` to the maximum index - one less than the length of your lists
- You can get a length of a list using `len`
- You can get a range using `range` (Python 3) or `xrange` (Python 2)

In your code,

- Having two loops is not what you need to do
- Your `if` cannot ever be true.

EDIT2: Changed "array" to "list", because Python has to be a special snowflake.

Comment: This is great, but I still have not learned this. Is there a way to for loop it?